# Get value from elements from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next table:

```
<table id="table_id">
   <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>Date</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><select>
             <option val="1">Math</option>
             <option val="2">Chemistry</option>
             <option val="3">Biology</option>
          </select></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txt_desc"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="date"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And the next javascript code for get the values

```
val_test_op = '';           
parent.$('#table_id option:selected').each(function (index,value){
   test = $.text(value).trim();
   if ( index === 0 && test || index % 1 === 0 && test )    {   
       val_test_op += index +' TEST: ' + test;
       return;
   }                    
})

val_test_input = '';
parent.$('#table_id td>input').each(function (index,value){
test = this.value;
    if ( index === 0 && test || index % 2 === 0 && test )   {
        texto_examen_input += index +' Description: ' + test;
        return;
    }
    if ( index === 1 && test || index % 3 === 0 && test )   {
        texto_examen_input += index +' Date: ' + test;
        return;
    }
})
```

My question is: ¿ How i get the value from the option:selected and input text in a only "each function" ?

Comment: Stick it in a form, and do `$(form).serialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a `each` function for getting values from fields in the table.

If you add `id`s to the fields, you could select those directly with jquery then use the `val` function to get their values easily.

```
<table id="table_id">
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select id="txt_test">
            <option val="1">Math</option>
            <option val="2">Chemistry</option>
            <option val="3">Biology</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt_desc"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt_date"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then with javascript:

```
val_test_op = $('#txt_test').val();
texto_examen_desc = $('#txt_desc').val();
texto_examen_date = $('#txt_date').val();
```

If you really want to use a single `each` function to get all the values, you could use the `:input` selector that jquery provides and do the following:

```
values = '';
$('#table_id').find(':input').each(function (index, input) {
    values += $(input).val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!. Now i have a better idea for solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

I added in a button to alert what the selected value is.

```
function myFunction(){
    var theSelect = document.getElementById("table_id").getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  var selectedOption = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].text;
  alert(selectedOption);
}

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e1hxn6kL/

Answer (score 0):

Give your select an ID such as id="opts"

Then

```
var opts = [];
$.each($("#opts:selected"),function(opt){
    opts.push(opt.Val());
}
var txt_desc = $("#txt_desc").Val();
var date = $("#date").Val();
```

Or similar